# How do I create a simple 'like' button using jquery.ajax()?

Tags: jquery

Trying to make a thumbs-up button (created using font awesome) that allows people to 'like' a comment. I'm trying to use a span instead of a button and I'm trying to submit some hidden fields that are within the span. Not sure if this is a good idea!

Would really appreciate some help as I don't think the data is right. I don't know how to tell what's being posted, but keep getting blank in console.log when I click the span.

**HTML**

```
<span class="fontawesome-uniF087 thumb">
<input type="hidden" name="userID" value="1111">
<input type="hidden" name="commentID" value="2222">
<input type="hidden" name="articleID" value="3333">
</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
    jQuery(".thumb").click(function() {

        var url = "AJAXthumbsup.asp";

        jQuery.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
               success: function(data) { // on success.. 

                    console.log(data);
                    jQuery(this).html(data); // update the span

               }
          });

        return false; 

    });
```

Many thanks,

Katie

Comment: This question should be closed being to broad

Answer (score 2):

**Why data variable is blank:**

The 'data' var in the success callback will have the data that are send as response from the server that you send the request. If you don't respond with some data this is why the console.log is blank.

**ex** if you AJAXthumbsup.asp echos "hello there", this string will be saved in the data variable.

**How to send data:**

in the data filed add an object with your data. For example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: { 
          userID: $(this).find('.userID'),
          commentID: $(this).find('.commentID')
          }
```

**About security and encryption:**

If you send via ajax the userID, commentID etc for authenticating the user and save the +1, anyone that know how to read the source code of javascript will be able to send fake requests as another user.

**A better way to do what you want:**

I think the best way to accomplish this is via cookies. 
Save a cookie which includes a unique key that is being produced in every login in your server side(ex. 1dkjdskajd343kj@jds) and also save it in your database. Then when a user send the ajax request to your server retrieve the unique id from the cookie , find from your database which user sends the request and proceed to the rest of your applications logic.

Comment: Thanks George for your quick response! You make a good point about security. Does this still apply if people are allowed to 'like' a comment without being logged in? Our users will be anonymous. I intend to drop a cookie on their PC using jQuery to prevent them liking the same comment multiple times. Do you think this will suffice? Either way they'll be able to clear their cookies and it doesn't really matter if they 'like' as someone else as there's no benefit to doing so over clearing cookies. Also, I'm now getting a Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation” error. Any idea why? Thanks again!

Comment: Saving a cookie to prevent multiple likes for normal users will work. But if someone wants to bypass this restriction he can create a very simple javascript code which deletes the cookie and sends a request for +1 in a loop, as a result he can in a few seconds give a lot of likes, in some minutes thousands +++ . I would recommend you to create a 'like' table in your database that keeps ip address and commentID. Then in every 'like' request on your server side you check if this ip has already liked the comment.